# 301 Redirect Dynamic to static URL - Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

For the life of me and all my years of experience with .htaccess I cannot get this simple redirect to work... I am totally stumped so any help would be great;

From:
http://www.offices-furniture.co.uk/pp?prod=fridgemaster-desk-fan.html

To:
http://www.offices-furniture.co.uk/fridgemaster-desk-fan.html

Should be simple, but ohhh no..

I'm using magento, own dedicated server so have full access to everything

Comment: I've tried using:

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /pp?prod=$1 [L]

but results in 500 server error

Also tried: RedirectMatch 301 ^pp?prod=(.*)\.htm$ http://www.offices-furniture.co.uk/$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this some time later. Basically Magento was interfering with the htaccess file, so I tested on another website;

http://www.office-desks.co.uk/solar-cantilever-combi-desks.html
is actually loading the result from
http://www.office-desks.co.uk/cat/product.php?prod=solar-cantilever-combi-desks.html

Now I have nice clean URL's wohoo :)

Here is my htaccess code which may help someone;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ cat/product.php?prod=$1

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ cat/cat.php?cat=$1

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ cat/cat.php?cat=$1
```

The lines in magento which was causing the problems was these (down to the wildcard);

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) m1_seourls.router.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) m1_seourls.router.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin  Make your transition to Magento go smoothly with this simple yet powerful URL redirect management tool.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smooth-move-seo-301-redirect-handler-3958.html

Comment: Thanks Ernesto but I just need the .htaccess code, i'm not moving software.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mbstrategic.com/02/301-redirects-for-dynamic-urls-to-static-pages-with-htaccess/

301 Redirects for Dynamic URLs to Static Pages with htaccess

Article id is necesary in htaccess, look excel table

Comment: Hi Ernest - i've read through that article in detail. The link to the excel download is corrupt. Thanks

Comment: For me link to excel is not corrupt. I use openoffice

Comment: i've just done the same thing with open office and used the tool. However the ouput;

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prod=fridgemaster-desk-fan.html$
 RewriteRule ^pp$ http://www.offices-furniture.co.uk? [R=301,L]

doesnt do anything at all

Comment: Try open file whith google spreadsheet   is necesary file id article id

Comment: pp is a page which exists within the back end of magento. "fridgemaster-desk-fan.html" is the dynamic variable and can be anything

Comment: In magento all article have id number. I think is necesary. you see the excel file. Sorry for my English.

Comment: pp is a page and its ID is "8"

Comment: line 1 in htaccess RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=7$ [NC]

Comment: line 2 in htaccess RewriteRule p/view.php http://www.offices-furniture.co.uk/fridgemaster-desk-fan.html ? [R=301,L]

Comment: Is possible  p/view.php no exact  sorry id=8 in line 1

Comment: Line 1: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=8$ [NC]
Line 2: RewriteRule p/view.php offices-furniture.co.uk/fridgemaster-desk-fan.html

This makes http://www.offices-furniture.co.uk/fridgemaster-desk-fan.html redirect to the homepage. Line 2 - are you sure you dont mean pp/view.php?

Comment: yes try   pp/view.php   but for mass change is necesary and timesaver  excel file